# Foreach operator and one string

Tags: c#

For example I have the code:

```
foreach (var item in _post)
{
   Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
}
```

How can I put this strings in item to one string? Sorry for my English.

Comment: Do you mean you want all the items' names in one line (string)?

Answer (score 2):

Try using [string.join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988350.aspx)

```
var result = string.Join("\n",_post.Select(s=>s.Name));
```

Comment: You should be joining them on '\n' to be in line with the OP's code.

Comment: @Servy Yeah you are right.. I did not notice a writeline.. Thanks :)

Comment: Regarding the code comment: He should not use `""` as separator, he should call `string.Concat` instead of `string.Join` in that situation.

Answer (score 1):

```
string aggregate = ""
foreach (var item in _post)
{
    aggregate += item.Name;
    aggregate += "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Aggregate method ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb548651.aspx)):

```
string result = _post.Select(x=> x.Name).Aggregate((x, y) => x + y);
```

Or if you want to do this in foreach loop, try this:

```
string result = "";
foreach (var item in _post)
{
   result += item.Name;
   Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
}
```

Comment: This is terribly, terribly inefficient for strings, as you're constantly discarding, recreating, and re-copying the same string values over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var item in _post)
   {
    str.AppendFormat("{0}, ",item);
   }

 Console.WriteLine(str.ToString());
```

Comment: Note that this solution will have a trailing comma space.

Comment: ^ Remove the comma, just leave a space.  str.AppendFormat("{0} ",item);